# How to get pytest to run all functions as test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, ini

I have looked around and I can't find a pytest.ini flag to pass in that says the equivalent of

```
def test_one():
   # you run this by default

def two():
   # despite not having test in the name you should also run this
```

reason: test function name lengths are getting to long when I'm being descriptive with naming and frankly it seems anti dry.

Comment: Did you try with a decorator?...Really not sure if this is doable and if pytest will consider it as a test case.

Comment: @IronFist what decorator would you suggest?

Comment: I mean...making your own wrapper...still like I said..I didn't test or try this.

Comment: But honestly, does adding `test_` to the beginning of your test function's name make it longer ?...I'm not sure if you can avoid that as it is a *requirement* and keep in mind that function with more descriptive names, makes debugging easier and code more readable!

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html)

```
# content of setup.cfg
# can also be defined in in tox.ini or pytest.ini file
[pytest]
python_files=check_*.py
python_classes=Check
python_functions=*_check
```

Replace `*_check` with just `*` in there and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as shown below, it will ask py.test collection tests from all python files.

```
# content of pytest.ini
[pytest]
python_files = *.py
```

you can check this part of document,

[customizing test collection to find all .py files](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#customizing-test-collection-to-find-all-py-files)

Answer (score 0):

You should set `*` to [python_functions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-python_functions) in [pytest.ini](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/reference/customize.html#pytest-ini) to run all functions as shown below:

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
python_functions = *
```

In addition, if you don't set `python_functions` in `pytest.ini` as shown below, then the functions prefixed with `test` are run according to [the doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-python_functions):

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
# python_functions = *
```